# SQLite error: "OperationalError; no such column:” when column does exist

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-insert, trading

I trying to grab one-year's worth of currency data from the TraderMade Python SDK and store that data in a SQLite database. I have created the DB already with the column headings I need (date, open, high, low, close).

I have written the following code to get and store the data:

```
conn = db.connect("MarketData.db")
c = conn.cursor()

def data():
    tm.set_rest_api_key([MY API KEY])
    request = tm.timeseries(
        currency='EURUSD',
        start="2022-01-01",
        end="2022-12-31",
        interval="daily",
        fields=["open", "high", "low", "close"]
        )
    print(request)
    stmt = '''INSERT INTO eurusd VALUES (?,?,?,?,?), (date, open, high, low, close)'''
    c.executemany(stmt, request)
    return


data()
conn.commit()
print('complete')
```

The data is coming from TraderMade fine as 'request' is printing fine:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8zaq.png)

However, I am getting the following error when I run the code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS5gD.png)

I have a date column in my DB. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code? My only thought is that the data is not being pulled in the correct format to store - but I'm not sure why as when 'request' prints it has 5 columns all with the correct column headings.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

The column names should come before the `values` clause:

```
stmt = '''INSERT INTO eurusd (date, open, high, low, close) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'''
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it - just gives me a different error:
"sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied."

Comment: When you do `c.executemany(stmt, request)` the bindings are provided in `request`. Are you sure that `request` contains exactly 5 values? If yes, why are you sure? How did you check that?